# C# application does not start on windows startup

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to start my app on windows startup.And also i am trying to start sql service if not started which is working properly but when i restart my system, app does not starts

- To register on startup

  ```
  RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
  ```

  key.SetValue("Attendence", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
- To Start SQL service

  `string PC_Name = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");
  System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS",PC_Name);
          if (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) || sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending))
          {
              sc.Start();
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
          }`

  - And in app.manifest

```
  <applicationRequestMinimum>
    <defaultAssemblyRequest permissionSetReference="Custom" />
    <PermissionSet class="System.Security.PermissionSet" version="1" Unrestricted="true" ID="Custom" SameSite="site" />
  </applicationRequestMinimum>
```

[regedit showing my app listed over there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXm0a.png)

Comment: Try this. Right Click on the Application and Select "Create Shortcut -> In Desktop". Now Copy paste the Shortcut in Startup Folder. If Windows 8 and above. windows+R (RUN) and Type "shell:startup".

Comment: I want that to be done by code

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
key.SetValue("Attendence", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
```

to:

```
key.SetValue("Attendence", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");
```

to provide the necessary quotes around the path (since the path has spaces in it).

Answer (score 0):

This might works, but if you need to start it straight away from starting your program then put this inside your Form1_Load code block

Code:

```
using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
        {
            key.SetValue("YourExecutable", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath + "\"");
        }
```